# PHP MYSQLI Prepared statements struggling with update

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've been trying various ways of doing this but just can't seem to get my update statement to work.

Below is my code I have included the select statement which works fine, errors do work when I do something wrong so it would suggest the syntax is correct, but for some reason it returns 0 rows affected. This I think would point to my command but there isn't anyway to my knowledge of debugging this more than I have.

I've tried the command in phpmyadmin and it seems to work fine.

If anyone can help I've been scratching my head for nearly a day :)

Working select statement:

```
$user_id = 101;
$stmt = $conn -> prepare('SELECT id, sign_on_signature, user_id FROM a_entry_form WHERE user_id = ?');

if (
    $stmt &&
    $stmt -> bind_param('s', $user_id) &&
    $stmt -> execute() &&
    $stmt -> store_result() &&
    $stmt -> bind_result($record_id, $signature, $user)
) {

    while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
        echo "$record_id - $signature: $user <br>";
    }

} else {
    echo 'Prepared Statement Error';
}
```

Failing update statement:

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare('UPDATE a_entry_form SET sign_on_signature = ? WHERE user_id = ? ');

$name = 'Joe';
$id = 101;

if (
    $stmt &&
    $stmt -> bind_param('si', $name, $id) &&
    $stmt -> execute() &&
    $stmt -> affected_rows === 1
) {
    echo 'Updated';
} else {
    echo 'Not updated';
  echo $conn -> error;
}
```

The above should execute the following which works fine:

`UPDATE a_entry_form SET sign_on_signature = 'bob' WHERE user_id = 101`

Comment: Did the update FAIL or was it just your overly complex IF Did you get anything from `$conn -> error;`??

Comment: If you remove the `$stmt -> affected_rows === 1` do you get the message you expect?

Comment: If `sign_on_signature` is not changed i.e. its already set to `bob` the affected_rows will be zero. Could that be your issue

Comment: Just remove $stmt -> affected_rows === 1 and try

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, it was a combination of two things:

`$stmt -> affected_rows === 1`

As it affected 2 rows it was always going to return false as it would have been 0 or 2 therefore I have changed this to:

`$stmt -> affected_rows > 0`

Or perhaps as mentioned, I just don't need it when the form is submitted unless I need to tell the user upon submission they haven't changed anything?

The other was as @RiggsFolly said if nothing has changed the result will be 0, I was still expecting it to return rows a human error on my part, I did not change the values between tests.